# Making Ctrl+Alt combinations available after switching the keys with Autohotkey

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, autohotkey

I want to switch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> on my Windows installation, and I use Autohotkey to do it via the script:

```
LCtrl::Alt
LAlt::Ctrl
```

This works most of time, but when I want to use a combined hotkey such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, it behaves as if I had only pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

How can I write the Autohotkey script to switch the keys, but still allow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>?

Answer (score 1):

```
LCtrl::
   Send, {AltDown}
   KeyWait, % A_ThisHotkey
   Send, {AltUp}
   Return

LAlt::
   Send, {CtrlDown}
   KeyWait, % A_ThisHotkey
   Send, {CtrlUp}
   Return
```

Comment: If you could elaborate somewhat, it would really increase the quality of your answer.